# How correctly connect redux to react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have react-native + redux application. In this application i have about 10 components (music, movies etc.)
But, i can't correctly connect redux to react-native. I have error "could not find store in either the context or props of..."

My App.js file

```
import App from './src/index';
export default App;
```

And my index.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { AppNavigator } from './nav/nav'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosMiddleware from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import reducer from './store/reducer';
import { listPosts } from './store/reducer';

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://xxxxxx.xxx',
    responseType: 'json'
});
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware(client)));

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <AppNavigator />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    let storedPosts = state.posts.map(repo => ({ key: repo.id, ...repo }));
    return {
        posts: storedPosts
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    listPosts
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: We cannot connect the `App` component because it renders the `Provider`. Any components that gets rendered within the `Provider` will have access to `connect` and `store`. In this case your `AppNavigator` can be connected.

Comment: Ok, i connected AppNavigator, but in components i don't see in props redux data.

Comment: You need to `connect` `every component` where you require data that is stored in `redux`. Make use of `mapStateToProps` to filter the required data and send that as the prop to the component.

Comment: Realy? Every component? But my application will be work slowly

Comment: Yes. You might have to look at some basic examples to see how it is connected(https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact). The app wont be slower because of redux(in most cases).